Error 100357 (P0000): Returned Series has a different number of elements than the input
Hi I am using a vectorized python udf - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-batch
I am making use of a snowflake app and have this code in the udf:
@vectorized(input=pandas.DataFrame, max_batch_size=25)
def detokenize(token):
 
     # Args:
    #   token (varchar): The tokens to be detokenized.
 
    token_values = token[0].apply(
        lambda x: {'token': x}).tolist()
    body = {
        'parameters': token_values
    }
    url = url1 + "/detokenize"
 
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.post(url, json=body)
        response.raise_for_status()
 
        response_as_json = sjson.loads(response.text)
 
        data = []
        for record in response_as_json['records']:
            data.append(record['value'])
 
    except Exception as error:
        return (f"An error occurred while performing detokenize: {error}")
    return pandas.Series(data)


When sending a query like this to a table which has one column - first_name string with 10k rows
SELECT test_app.code_schema.detokenize(first_name), first_name from snowflake_benchmarking;

I get this error intermittently
100357 (P0000): Returned Series has a different number of elements than the input, with 58 elements in the output versus 23 in the input in function detokenize with handler udf.detokenize

I have tested this endpoint with curl outside snowflake and it works. url1 is just the base url here. There is a limitation of 25 detokenization possible in one batch.
How does this get debugged, I have added log_level: debug as well to the manifest.yml in the native app but this hardly helps.
What is the reason for this and how do I resolve this?

It would seem some first_name values have multiple records in their response as that seems to be the only way you could get more result values than input values.
